# Weird asterisks and text missalignment in table header

Tags: tables

I have created a table with the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside]{article}


\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\DeclareSIUnit \annum{a}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{c 
                c 
                c 
                c
                S[table-format=3] 
                S[table-format=3.1]
                S[table-format=3.1]
                S[table-format=1.3]
                S[table-format=3.1]
                S[table-format=1.4]
                S[table-format=2.2]
                }
            
    \toprule
    \makecell{Reservoir\\ (Location)}  
    & \makecell{Dam/SBT \\ Commissioning \\ year} 
      & \makecell{SBT \\ Type \\ (A/B)}
        & \makecell{SBT \\ length \\ {[\si{\metre}]}}
          & \makecell{$Q_d$ \\ {[\si{\cubic\metre\per\second}]}}
            & \makecell{$t_{op}$ \\ {[\si{\day\per\annum}]}}
              & \makecell{$V_{s,m,\mathrm{out}}$ \\ {[\SI{E3}{\cubic\metre\per\annum}]}}
                & \makecell{$\sigma_{s,m}$ \\ {[\si{\mL\per\L}]}}
                  & \makecell{MAS \\  {[\SI{E3}{\cubic\m\per\annum}]}} 
                    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{Bypassing\\ efficiencies  $\eta_{b}$ }} \\
                    \cmidrule{10-11}                
                                    
     &  &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &  {$\eta_{\sigma}$} {[\si{\percent}]} & {$\eta_v$} {[\si{\percent}]}\\
    
    \midrule
    
    Asahi (JP) & 1987/1998  & A              & 2384  & 140   & 14.5      & 65.0      & 0.371   & 109.4   & 0.0371 & 59.43 \\
    Miwa (JP) & 1952/2004  & B               & 4308  & 300   & 2.5       & 400.0     & 6.173   & 685.0   & 0.6173 & 58.39 \\
    Palagnedra (CH) & 1952/1974  & A         & 1760  & 250   & 5.0       & 92.0      & 0.852   & 200.0   & 0.0852 & 46.00 \\
    Pfaffensprung (CH) & 1921/1922  & ns     & 280   & 220   & 150.0     & 94.0      & 0.033   & 100.0   & 0.0033 & 94.00 \\
    Rempen (CH) & 1924/1983  & A             & 450   & 80    & 3.0       & 4.0       & 0.193   & ns      & 0.0193 & ns \\
    Runcahez (CH) & 1961/1961  & A           & 572   & 56    & 2.5       & 17.7      & 1.463   & 21.2    & 0.1463 & 83.49 \\
    Solis (CH) & 1986/2012  & B              & 968   & 170   & 1.0       & 68.0      & 4.630   & 103.0   & 0.4630  & 66.02 \\
    Val d'Ambra (CH) & 1967/1967  & A        & 512   & 85    & 2.5       & 8.0       & 0.436   & 8.7     & 0.0436  & 91.95 \\
    
    \bottomrule
    
    {$= V_s,out/V_s,in$} \\
    
    
    
    \end{tabular}
  \label{tab:addlabel}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

For some reason, I am getting these weird asterisks in the headers, and the headers are also misaligned. The table is probably not shrunk due to the margin (red) since it is still quite far from the table's margin.

[image]

I would appreciate your help and suggestions.

Comment: A makecell command that is used inside of a S column should be surrounded by a set of {}. Additionally, the table-format options of the first two S type columns seem to be wrong. For the first one, use 4 instead of 3, and for the second 3 instead of 3.1.

Comment: @leandriis it worked, thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based in the very good  answer from leandris I tested the package `nicematrix`. It provides a command `\Block` that allows the use of `\\` inside the cell and also makes blocks of columns/rows. So the code is simplified, although it requires a second compilation if the format is changed.

The result is the same. I only added some vertical space between the cells and raised the  `\cmidrule{10-11}` for a better look.

The stretching of the cells can also be obtain using  `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}` after `\centering` in either answers.

[image: nm2]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside]{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\DeclareSIUnit \annum{a}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{nicematrix} % added

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{NiceTabular}[%   
        cell-space-top-limit = 5pt, % stretch the cells
        cell-space-bottom-limit = 5pt
        ]
        {c 
         c 
         c 
         S[table-format=4]
         S[table-format=3] 
         S[table-format=3.1]
         S[table-format=3.1]
         S[table-format=1.3]
         S[table-format=3.1]
         S[table-format=1.4]
         S[table-format=2.2]
                }            
    \toprule
      \Block[c]{}{Reservoir\\ (Location)}  
    &   \Block[c]{}{Dam/SBT \\ Commissioning \\ year} 
      &   \Block[c]{}{SBT \\ Type \\ (A/B)}
        &   \Block[c]{}{SBT \\ length \\ {[\si{\metre}]}}
          &   \Block[c]{}{$Q_d$ \\ {[\si{\cubic\metre\per\second}]}}
            &   \Block[c]{}{$t_{op}$ \\ {[\si{\day\per\annum}]}}
              &   \Block[c]{}{$V_{s,m,\mathrm{out}}$ \\ {[\SI{E3}{\cubic\metre\per\annum}]}}
                &   \Block[c]{}{$\sigma_{s,m}$ \\ {[\si{\mL\per\L}]}}
                  &   \Block[c]{}{MAS \\  {[\SI{E3}{\cubic\m\per\annum}]}} 
                    & \Block{1-2}{Bypassing\\ efficiencies  $\eta_{b}$ } \\[-7pt] % raise the next rule
                    \cmidrule{10-11}                
                                    
     &  &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &  {$\eta_{\sigma}$} {[\si{\percent}]} & {$\eta_v$} {[\si{\percent}]}\\
    
    \midrule
    
    Asahi (JP) & 1987/1998  & A              & 2384  & 140   & 14.5      & 65.0      & 0.371   & 109.4   & 0.0371 & 59.43 \\
    Miwa (JP) & 1952/2004  & B               & 4308  & 300   & 2.5       & 400.0     & 6.173   & 685.0   & 0.6173 & 58.39 \\
    Palagnedra (CH) & 1952/1974  & A         & 1760  & 250   & 5.0       & 92.0      & 0.852   & 200.0   & 0.0852 & 46.00 \\
    Pfaffensprung (CH) & 1921/1922  & ns     & 280   & 220   & 150.0     & 94.0      & 0.033   & 100.0   & 0.0033 & 94.00 \\
    Rempen (CH) & 1924/1983  & A             & 450   & 80    & 3.0       & 4.0       & 0.193   & ns      & 0.0193 & ns \\
    Runcahez (CH) & 1961/1961  & A           & 572   & 56    & 2.5       & 17.7      & 1.463   & 21.2    & 0.1463 & 83.49 \\
    Solis (CH) & 1986/2012  & B              & 968   & 170   & 1.0       & 68.0      & 4.630   & 103.0   & 0.4630  & 66.02 \\
    Val d'Ambra (CH) & 1967/1967  & A        & 512   & 85    & 2.5       & 8.0       & 0.436   & 8.7     & 0.0436  & 91.95 \\
    
    \bottomrule
    
    {$= V_s,out/V_s,in$} \\    
    
    \end{NiceTabular}
  \label{tab:addlabel}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I know it is a separate question, but I think it is not worth starting a new thread for; how can I also align the "ns"s in the cells along the right cell-edge as we see with the numbers? In this table, it does not look bad, but I have another one, where I would like to align the "ns" text with the numbers otherwise it just looks off.

Comment: Change the columns definitions from         {c 
    c 
    c 
    S[table-format=4]
    S[table-format=3] 
    S[table-format=3.1]
    S[table-format=3.1]
    S[table-format=1.3]
    S[=3.1]
    S[table-format=1.4]
    S[table-format=2.2]
                 }  to         {c 
         c 
         r<{\quad} 
         r<{\enspace} 
        r<{\enspace} 
        r <{\enspace} 
        r <{\quad}  
       r <{\enspace} 
        r<{\quad}  
        r<{\enspace} 
  r <{\enspace} 
                }

Comment: The columns, except the first two, will be right aligned plus a small left displacement to center them with their headings. The S columns are not needed because all values have the same number of decimals.

Answer (score 2):

The example code from your question results in a bunch of error messages upon trying to compile. Since you included a screenshot and mentioned "weird asterisks in the headers" and misalignment: Please never ever ignore error messages! Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.

The error messages in this example code are caused by the use of `\makecell` inside of an `S` type column. To correct that, surround each `\makecell` command with an extra set of `{}`. In fact, everything that is not a number but inside of a `S` type column should be surrounded by a set of `{}` to "hide" it from the parsing mechanism. Conents enclosed in a set of `{}  will be horizontally centered inside of their column.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside]{article}


\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\DeclareSIUnit \annum{a}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{c 
                c 
                c 
                S[table-format=4]
                S[table-format=3] 
                S[table-format=3.1]
                S[table-format=3.1]
                S[table-format=1.3]
                S[table-format=3.1]
                S[table-format=1.4]
                S[table-format=2.2]
                }
            
    \toprule
    \makecell{Reservoir\\ (Location)}  
    & \makecell{Dam/SBT \\ Commissioning \\ year} 
      & \makecell{SBT \\ Type \\ (A/B)}
        & {\makecell{SBT \\ length \\ {[\si{\metre}]}}}
          & {\makecell{$Q_d$ \\ {[\si{\cubic\metre\per\second}]}}}
            & {\makecell{$t_{op}$ \\ {[\si{\day\per\annum}]}}}
              & {\makecell{$V_{s,m,\mathrm{out}}$ \\ {[\SI{E3}{\cubic\metre\per\annum}]}}}
                & {\makecell{$\sigma_{s,m}$ \\ {[\si{\mL\per\L}]}}}
                  & {\makecell{MAS \\  {[\SI{E3}{\cubic\m\per\annum}]}}} 
                    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{Bypassing\\ efficiencies  $\eta_{b}$ }} \\
                    \cmidrule{10-11}                
                                    
     &  &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &  {$\eta_{\sigma}$ [\si{\percent}]} & {$\eta_v$ [\si{\percent}]}\\
    
    \midrule
    
    Asahi (JP)         & 1987/1998  & A      & 2384  & 140   & 14.5      & 65.0      & 0.371   & 109.4   & 0.0371  & 59.43 \\
    Miwa (JP)          & 1952/2004  & B      & 4308  & 300   & 2.5       & 400.0     & 6.173   & 685.0   & 0.6173  & 58.39 \\
    Palagnedra (CH)    & 1952/1974  & A      & 1760  & 250   & 5.0       & 92.0      & 0.852   & 200.0   & 0.0852  & 46.00 \\
    Pfaffensprung (CH) & 1921/1922  & ns     & 280   & 220   & 150.0     & 94.0      & 0.033   & 100.0   & 0.0033  & 94.00 \\
    Rempen (CH)        & 1924/1983  & A      & 450   & 80    & 3.0       & 4.0       & 0.193   & {ns}    & 0.0193  & {ns} \\
    Runcahez (CH)      & 1961/1961  & A      & 572   & 56    & 2.5       & 17.7      & 1.463   & 21.2    & 0.1463  & 83.49 \\
    Solis (CH)         & 1986/2012  & B      & 968   & 170   & 1.0       & 68.0      & 4.630   & 103.0   & 0.4630  & 66.02 \\
    Val d'Ambra (CH)   & 1967/1967  & A      & 512   & 85    & 2.5       & 8.0       & 0.436   & 8.7     & 0.0436  & 91.95 \\
    
    \bottomrule
    
    {$= V_s,out/V_s,in$} \\
    
    
    
    \end{tabular}
  \label{tab:addlabel}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```